# How to show notification content on lockscreen - Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am using NotificationCompat.Builder to create a notification:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent( this,
                                    MyActivity.class );
PendingIntent resultingActivityPendingIntent = getPendingIntent( activityIntent );

// create notification for foreground service
m_notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this );
m_notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher );
m_notificationBuilder.setTicker( "some text" );
m_notificationBuilder.setContentTitle( "some text" ) );
m_notificationBuilder.setContentIntent( resultingActivityPendingIntent );
startForeground( ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                 m_notificationBuilder.build() );
```

The notification functions as expected in the status bar and notification dropdown, but for the lockscreen, it shows this:

```
com.myname.mypackage 
Contents hidden
```

How do I change the line where my package name is?

I have tried setting content text and content info in the notification builder, but it doesn't change anything.

There must be something obvious I'm missing because other apps, even if their content is hidden, will have that line say something relevant, like:

```
USB connectivity
Contents hidden
```

I am using SDK 19, build tools 19, targeting 19, min SDK 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:  I needed to set the android:label field in my `<application>` node in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 5):

NotificationCompat.Builder sets a default visibility flag of [VISIBILITY_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#VISIBILITY_PRIVATE).  Instead, explicitly set it to [VISIBILITY_PUBLIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) with a call to [setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setVisibility%28int%29).

Comment: Hm, visibility doesn't seem to be available on SDK 19.  Also, based on the documentation, it seems that visibility flags pertain to the "Contents hidden" line, as opposed to the "title" (or whatever it's called) of the notification.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the wrong constants.  They should have been pointed to the compat library versions, not the platform.  (The javadoc links also appear to be incorrect).  Edited.  Notification privacy is a new feature, yes, so you won't be affecting older platforms with this.

Comment: Doug, thank you for your response.  You provided me a helpful clue.  I ended up reading the Notifications design doc and saw that the description for VISIBILITY_PRIVATE is "On the lock screen, shows basic information about the existence of this notification, including its icon *and the name of the app that posted it*."  I then looked at how to set my app's name.  Turns out, that was the problem:  I hadn't set the android:label field in my <application> node in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it another way also.

You can call the *setVisibility()* method of the notificationCompat.Builder where you can set a **VISIBILITY_PUBLIC** flag, that will mirror whatever your title and contentText is when the screen is unlocked.

Changing the label field will also change the name of your application in the app drawer.